# How does gc Go handle heap allocation?

Tags: go

Does gc Go (specifically go1.11) pre-allocates a chunk of memory and take from it for each allocation (like JVM), or it allocates every time a variable is created, and is it a kernel call (malloc)?

If it is one kernel call per allocation, that would make variable creation expensive. How can I force allocation on the stack/heap?

Comment: The allocator is specific to the implementation, and changes over time. In the common implementation, you can't _force_ allocations on the stack, but you can try to keep them from escaping. It's generally not too difficult to keep an allocation within the stack when you need to.

Comment: To tack on to what @JimB said, the compiler is pretty good at escape analysis. Any variable that never leaves the function where it's allocated should live on the heap (not difficult since Go passes by copying).

Comment: @JimB I update the question as I am mainly concerned with gc go 1.11. Can you elaborate on how to "keep an allocation within the stack"?

Comment: go 1.12 is in beta

Comment: @texasbruce: if a value isn't too big for the stack, and doesn't escape the scope of the function, then it is generally allocated on the stack. If you want specific details on this in a specific version, it's probably better to ask the mailing list. If you don't actually have a problem yet, then there's no reason to worry about theoretical allocations that haven't happened.

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in various places, like [the FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#stack_or_heap):

> **How do I know whether a variable is allocated on the heap or the stack?**
>
> From a correctness standpoint, you don't need to know. Each variable
>   in Go exists as long as there are references to it. The storage
>   location chosen by the implementation is irrelevant to the semantics
>   of the language.
>
> The storage location does have an effect on writing efficient
>   programs. When possible, the Go compilers will allocate variables that
>   are local to a function in that function's stack frame. However, if
>   the compiler cannot prove that the variable is not referenced after
>   the function returns, then the compiler must allocate the variable on
>   the garbage-collected heap to avoid dangling pointer errors. Also, if
>   a local variable is very large, it might make more sense to store it
>   on the heap rather than the stack.
>
> In the current compilers, if a variable has its address taken, that
>   variable is a candidate for allocation on the heap. However, a basic
>   escape analysis recognizes some cases when such variables will not
>   live past the return from the function and can reside on the stack.

---

Go's memory allocation is carefully optimized for its needs, for example with a [custom malloc](https://golang.org/src/runtime/malloc.go). I suspect you have a slightly different underlying question/problem that you're struggling with - it would be better to ask that instead. If this is just exploration/curiosity, you'll have to make your question much more specific.